# Virtualbox completely disabled my ethernet and wireless network connections

Tags: wireless-networking, virtualbox, networking, connection

After installing VirtualBox 3.1.6 for Windows, my computer's network connections were completely disabled. The wireless isn't working, not even the ethernet landline. Even "ipconfig" doesn't seem to respond to any commands.

Can anybody help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you restore using System Restore? Before I do any virtualization work (virtualbox, vmware, etc) I always take a System Restore point.

Comment: I ended up doing just that. Now I have to stick with Virtual PC until VirtualBox fixes this issue.